# Object in the workspace in R

Tags: r, object, stata

I am trying to save the `stata` data (`data.dta`) as `R` data and then load the data using the `paste` function and then assign the name using `get` and `paste` function.

```
library(foreign)
getwd()
"C:/Users/Vista/Documents/project"
year<-2010
income2010x.dta<-read.dta("data.dta")
save(income2010x.dta,file="income2010x.rda")
load( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) )
z <- get( paste0( "income" , year , "x.dta" ) )  # works
z <- get( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) ) # doesn't work 
z
Error in get(income2010x.rda) : object 'income2010x.rda' not found
ls()
income2010x.dta
...
```

I find that `income2010x.dta` is stored as the object after these steps but `income2010x.rda` is not. So, `z <- get( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) )` didn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`income2010x.dta<-read.dta("data.dta")`

creates a data.frame call ed `income2010x.dta` within the workspace.

`save` allows you to save many objects, and when you `load` them they will have the same names as when you saved them.

you can use `saveRDS` to save a single object and `readRDS` to read it to another name

```
saveRDS(income2010x.dta,file="income2010x.rda")
income2010x.rda <- readRDS('income2010x.rda')
```

That being said, I don't understand why you need two copies, or why you are using `get` to create a third copy of the same object as `z`

Comment: Why is R looking for something with "2010" in its name when you set `year` to 2000?

Comment: @mnel: Thanks. Using save doesn't create the .rda object. So, I tried using load.  `income2010x.rda <- readRDS('income2010x.rda')` generates the error.

@NockCox: I edited that now.

Comment: Did you use `saveRDS`? as my solution does?

Comment: @mnel: I got an error because I missed `RDS`. Now, I corrected it and I see both `income2010x.rda` and `income2010x.dta` in the `workspace`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
load( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) )
```

.... You get (in the colloquial sense of "acquire" or "access" or "recover") an object (or objects) named whatever named it had when it (they)  were saved. In this case you would have an object named 'income2010x.dta' but no object named "income2010x.rda", so this "get" in the restricted meaning of the R function:

```
z <- get( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) )
```

.... as you observed ..."doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Is there any other way to ask R to read .rda file using get?

Comment: `get` is used to access objects in the workspace. `*.rda` files are not in the workspace. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have `stata` files and I need `rda` version of these files in workspace. How can I do that?

Comment: There's no such thing as an .rda file in the workspace. `.rda` files are compressed binary representations of R objects that exist on a serial device, usually a disk.. You already know how to create an R object from a `.dta` file. So what is the problem?

Comment: If there is the R object in the workspace, then I am still not clear why I am getting the error `z <- get( paste0( "income" , year , "x.rda" ) )`

Comment: Because the object is a `data.frame` called `income2010x.dta`, the result of `income2010x.dta<-read.dta("data.dta")`

Comment: If you wanted to observe an error condition, execute `rm(income2010x.dta)` after saving the 'income2010x.rda' file (which is not an R object). Then try to `get` it.